# How to disable buffering with apache2 and mod_proxy_fcgi?

Tags: apache, buffer, mod-proxy, fastcgi, apache2.4

I'm using mod_proxy_fcgi with apache 2.4 on a debian Jessie with my C++ application which does ServerSentEvents with libfcgipp.

My problem is, that apache still buffers my response data. I confirmed that it isn't buffered by the libfcgipp library by using wireshark: After starting the fcgi application via `spawn-fcgi`, the data gets send to the apache web server as soon as possible. But in my browser (which I use for testing, later there will be a C++ client) it only shows up after I "killed"/closed the sending request in the server application.

So I assume I need to disable buffering for either apache or mod_proxy_fcgi (or both). But I cannot find the appropriate documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Do you have `mod_cache` module?

Comment: It is only in `mods-available` but not in `mods-enabled`, so I guess it is not enabled.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong term here. I meant "Buffering", not "caching".

Comment: Have you tried [ProxyIOBufferSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyiobuffersize) and [ProxyReceiveBufferSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyreceivebuffersize) directives?

Comment: How should I use them? zero means system default, so I cannot disable buffering via these, can I?

Comment: Buffering is necessary to pass data, so you can't set it to zero. But you can  set it to minimal acceptable value for this location.

Comment: Does not help, tough.

Answer (score 6):

As the result of [a subsequent discussion on the httpd-dev mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/5ed3ba235792f95305a75b3f986567779103650f8e516a8981515fbb%40%3Cdev.httpd.apache.org%3E), support for `flushpackets` and `flushwait` was added to `mod_proxy_fcgi` in [r1802040](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk@1802040) and backported for Apache 2.4.31 in [r1825765](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x@1825765). If you are using Apache 2.4.31 or later, you can disable buffering using `<Proxy flushpackets=on>` as described in the [BigPipe documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/big-pipe/bigpipe-environment-requirements#s-apache-with-php-fpm-fastcgi):

```apache
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    # Note: The only part that varies is /path/to/app.sock
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>

# Define a matching worker.
# The part that is matched to the SetHandler is the part that
# follows the pipe. If you need to distinguish, "localhost; can
# be anything unique.
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10>
</Proxy>
```

**Note:**  `flushpackets` and `flushwait` are currently only included in the [Apache `mod_proxy_fcgi` documentation for `trunk`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) because [r1808129](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk@1808129) has not been backported to the 2.4.x branch.

Answer (score 5):

A few notes, since I just spent the past few hours experimenting to find the answer to this question:

1. It's not possible to *entirely* disable output buffering when using `mod_proxy`/`mod_proxy_fcgi`, however, you can still have responses streamed in chunks.
2. It seems, based on my experimentation, that chunks have to be at least 4096 bytes before the output will be flushed to the browser.
3. You *can* disable output buffering with the `mod_fastcgi` or `mod_fcgi` module, but those mods aren't as popular/widely used with Apache 2.4.
4. If you have `mod_deflate` enabled and don't set `SetEnv no-gzip 1` for the virtualhost/directory/etc. that's streaming data, then gzip will not allow the buffer to flush until the request is complete.

I was testing things out to see how to best use Drupal 8's new BigPipe functionality for streaming requests to the client, and I posted some more notes in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/532).

Comment: One work around is to right pad your SSE response to 4096 with "\n"

Comment: Can anyone point me to the Apache code where the `4096` buffer size is defined? My testing has shown that `4089` bytes are enough, are some FCGI transport data counted as well?