# Using PHP and Server Sent Events (flushing with proxy_fcgi)

Tags: php, apache, server-sent-events

I use Ubuntu 17.04, Apache 2.4, proxy_fcgi, and php-fpm. Everything works and connects nicely, except for flushing for Server Sent Events.

Flushing used to work nicely with mod_fastcgi and fastcgiexternalserver with "-flush". Now with Ubuntu 17.04, it doesn't include mod_fastcgi, and proxy_fcgi is recommended.

With proxy_fcgi I've disabled gzip, output buffering, use "Content-Encoding: none", the only real way for connection_aborted and flush to work is if you send around 32K (I'm guessing this is because of proxy buffering?)

It says in the Apache Docs that you cannot set ProxyReceiveBufferSize or ProxyIOBufferSize less than 512.

There really should be an easier way to do this with proxy_fcgi.

Example code of sending data for Server Sent Events:

```
while (!connection_aborted() ) {
  echo('data: {}' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
  flush();
} // While //
```

Edit: I've tried ob_flush() too, but I disabled Output Buffering (ob_*) with ob_end_clean() previously, and ob_flush() will return an error.

Comment: Questions on professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com/).

Comment: This is related to PHP Programming.. Sorry I didn't make that clear, should I include example code that fails to work?

Comment: I doubt it is related (as you said you've disabled output buffering, which I'm guessing meant PHP's output buffering), but can you try `ob_flush();flush();` where you currently `flush()`?

Comment: Yep. I've disabled output buffering (ob) with ob_end_clean(). You know it's disabled when it gives you errors saying there is no buffer when you call ob_flush(). It's possibly just a bug with mod_proxy_fcgi? Because it works with mod_fastcgi and "-flush"?

Edit: Maybe you guys are right, it's probably not a PHP thing at this point. I read on another site that it was. I was kinda hoping someone would have success with Server Sent Events and PHP (with mod_proxy_fcgi), I think it would help others in the same boat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628918/disabling-output-buffer-with-apache-and-php-fpm-via-mod-proxy/60219588#60219588 explains how I got it working for me. The short answer is:  `fastcgi_finish_request( )`

Answer (score 1):

Albeit this question has been asked some years ago, I just ran into a similar problem with Apache 2.4 and `mod_fcgid`. The PHP application did directly return data without buffering (tested with internal server `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 index.php`) - but it was buffered when being used with Apache.

The following configuration disables output buffering for `mod_fcgid` (default size is 65536 bytes)

```
FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
```

https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#FcgidOutputBufferSize

Comment: Yup, I believe I was able to do it with mod_fcgid when I was working on that project, but I needed to use "proxy_fcgi" (which is the one that was still buffering). Thanks for chiming in though after all this time!