Question regarding ob_flush and flush not working on FPM
I have below code and want to show echo one by one but whole result returns at once

<?php 



for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){

  

  sleep(1); 

  echo "$i\n";

  

  ob_flush();

    flush();

  

}


It is ok in CGI but not in FPM (PHP 8.3 - apache 2.4)
I have tried several things to solve this problem, but none of these solutions worked.
Here are some of them:
ini_set('output_buffering','Off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();

Any solution?

PHP is not the best language to choose when you want to "animate" something in the browser. Have a look at Javascript. The problem is that PHP (FPM) outputs in bigger blocks. So it waits until there's enough data to send to the browser. You can solve this by outputting stuff that's hidden in between each step. We're talking kilobytes of hidden data here.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628918/disabling-output-buffer-with-apache-and-php-fpm-via-mod-proxy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707792/how-to-disable-buffering-with-apache2-and-mod-proxy-fcgi

This may help: Streaming PHP - disabling output buffering in PHP, Apache, Nginx, and Varnish @ Jeff Geerling.

If you want to continue with FPM, you need ob_end_clean before first echo but with enough count, so the final status may be like this

<?php

while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){

  sleep(1); 
  echo "$i\n";

  ob_flush();
  flush();

}



Why would this be helpful? By default the nesting level is zero, so the code you added does nothing.

I tried the code and it worked.
